# How to implement a filter in angular 7

Tags: angular, filter, angular7

I'm trying to implement a filter on my **matTable** with a **DataSource(cdk)**. Now the filter from the Material Example doesn't work since it's not a **MatDataSource** and after a long search, I'm still not sure of a good way to implement it and the different components that would play a part.

I found some examples using pipes (though the official material says it's rather inefficient) and creating a reference for another component of already filtered data. Could someone explain me an efficient way of implementing a filter and the components with their different functions?

Comment: Do you really want efficient way? Use `MatTableDataSource`.

Comment: What do you tried so far ?